# Unexpected results from Python if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, user-input

Here is my code which is producing some unexpected results when input value is changed. (I know that there are lot of comments in it, I was using that as a means of debugging).

```
age = 0

age = input("please enter your age ")
#print(age)
#int(age)
#print(type(age))
age1 = int(age)
#print(type(age1))
print(age1)
if age1 > 30:
    #ageV = "old"
    print("old")
else: age1 < 30
#ageV  = "young"
print("young")
#print(ageV)
```

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in line `else: age1 < 30` second condition is not needed, just write this part as:

```
if age1 > 30:
    print("old")
else:
    print("young")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are only two possibilities here:

1. Age is greater than 30
2. Age is equal to or less than 30

So, you only need one if statement, and the 2nd possibility will be executed under **else**, like so:

```
if age1 > 30: 
 print("Old")
else: 
 print("Young")
```